# clion can't resolve std types

Tags: c++, c++11, std, clion

I've searched some similar questions,like [Clion can't resolve c++11 std types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44499735/clion-cant-resolve-c11-std-types), and did as the asker did, but the Clion still unrecognized the std variables, and asked me to use std::string instead of string. This can be resolved by adding `using namespace std` at the top of a file, but I don't like to add this code in every file, so how can I resolve this problem?
this is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(myapp)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
include_directories(".")
set(HeadFileDirList "")
file(GLOB SRCH_LIST comm2/*.h comm2/*/*.h comm2/*/*/*.h comm2/*/*/*/*.h comm2/*/*/*/*/*.h mmcomm/*.h mmcomm/*/*.h mmcomm/*/*/*.h mmcomm/*/*/*/*.h mmcomm/*/*/*/*/*.h)
foreach(src ${SRCH_LIST})
    string(REGEX REPLACE "[^/\\\\]+$" "" HeadFileDir ${src})
    message(STATUS ${HeadFileDir})
    include_directories(${HeadFileDir})
endforeach()
add_executable(myapp main.cpp)
```

and this is Clion error
[clion error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpSVk.png)

Comment: I found the reason, because there are some statements in `comm2` lib, but I didn't include this dir, when I copy this dir under my project, it works right....

Answer (score 0):

`std` types live in the `std` namespace, and hence must either be qualified using `std::` or with the using-statement: `using namespace std;`. In your case, you would replace `string` with `std::string`, and likewise for other names in `std` such as `std::cout`.

Comment: thanks for your reply! it was my fault, now it works fine